# Angular Unit Testing: How to check if the spied upon method is getting the correct argument?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Let's say we have  a method called `Method1` which accepts and object
 `obj={ name: 'jack', phone: '123' }`

as you can see there are two properties here, name and phone.

Method1 internally calls Method2 with `obj.phone` as argument.

[FIDDLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-fkwvmg?file=app/app.component.spec.ts)

```
export class AppComponent {  
  method1(obj: any) {
    this.method2(obj.phone);
  }
  method2(val) {

  }
}
```

I would like to check if method2 was called and also if the correct argument was passed to it. Which in this case will always be phone property of obj.

Is callFake() the solution? How do I do it?

**Code that doesn't work:**

```
it('should do something', () => {
    let obj = { name: 'jack', phone: '123' }
    let passedarg;
    let spy = spyOn(subject, 'method2').and.callFake(function (arg) {
      passedarg = arg;
    });
    expect(obj).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj.phone);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're testing currently. Are you checking that `method2` is called with the `phone` property of the object passed as an argument to `method1`?

In your test currently, you spy on `method2` and provide a mock implementation (callFake). Then you assert that a javascript object `obj` has been called with the `phone` property that it holds. You need to call the function itself `subject.method1(obj)` and then you can see whether or not the spy was called.

If that is what you were trying to achieve, I think this what you might be looking for:

```
  it('should do something', () => {
    let obj = { name: 'jack', phone: '123' };
    spyOn(subject, 'method2');
    subject.method1(obj);
    expect(subject.method2).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj.phone);
  });
```

Comment: what the hell? I missed out the subject.method1(ob) part while copy pasting the code  but  why did it not occur to me that I could just use toHaveBeenCalledWith()? thanks